# How do I write this old piece of BASIC as a PHP Function?

Tags: php, function, basic

Assume the following variable values were set earlier in the code:

`LSLATHOR = 1780`, `NRSLATVER = 34`

Then I have these two lines of GWBASIC:

```
100 PITCHHOR=(LSLATHOR/(NRSLATVER+1))  :  LSLATHOR=PITCHHOR*(NRSLATVER+1)
110 IF PITCHHOR>72 THEN NRSLATVER=NRSLATVER+1:GOTO 100
120 LPRINT "HORIZONTAL PITCH is equal to : ";PITCHHOR;
```

Now if I wanted to put this logic as a PHP function how would I go about it?:

```
function calc_h($slat_length_h, $slat_qty_v) {

    $pitch_h = ($slat_length_h / ($v_slat_qty + 1));

    if ($pitch_h > 72) {            

            while ($pitch_h > 72) {                    
                $v_slat_qty += 1;
                $slat_length_h = $pitch_h * ($v_slat_qty + 1);
                $pitch_h = ($slat_length_h / ($v_slat_qty + 1));                 
            }

    }     

    return $pitch_h;
}

$slat_length_h = 1780;
$slat_qty_v = 34;

echo calc_h($slat_length_h, $slat_qty_v);
```

What you need to know is that a condition will sometimes exist where `PITCHHOR > 72` then it needs to adjust/re-calculate the $pitch_h according to the GWBasic script.

I hope I provided enough info. Ty vm.

Comment: That `if` around your while loop is redundant, they check the same condition. But what is your actual question? You have both functions, test if they produce the same result for a number of inputs.

Comment: I don't think my PHP function is correct. What do I have to adjust to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write as follows. But since you have the original code, you can simply try to plug in a few sample values and compare the results.

```
function calc_pitchhor($lslathor, $nrslatver) {
  do {
        $pitchhor = ($lslathor/($nrslatver+1));
        $lslathor = $pitchhor*($nrslatver+1);
        ++$nrslatver;
  } while($pitchhor > 72)

  return $pitchhor;
}


$lslathor = 1780;
$nrslatver = 34;

echo "HORIZONTAL PITCH is equal to: ", calc_pitchhor($slat_length_h, $slat_qty_v);
```